# How to search a lookup based on partial match of field values of a base search in splunk

Tags: splunk, spl

I am trying to combine 2 searches where the outer search passes a value to the inner search and then appends the results. Let me explain:

As of right now, I am searching a set of logs that happens to include people's names and their request type when they call the bank. The one I am focused on is "withdraw inquiry." So we get a list of all people who try to withdraw money based on the following base search.

```
index=myIndex sourcetype=mySource request_type="withdraw inquiry"
| xmlkv DetailXML
| stats count, values(phone_number), values(activity_summary), values(request_type) values(email) by acct_num name_last name_first
| where count > 1
| sort - count
```

which results in a table that looks like this:

| account number | name_first | name_last | call count | values(phone_number) | value(activity_summary) | values(email) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456678 | smith | john | 3 | 1235550987 | withdraw inquiry | john.smith@company.com |

This is great but I'd like to append or add another column with info that comes from a lookup table entitled  Previously_Compromised_Accounts.csv which looks like this

| user | date | intel_source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jsmith001 | 26DEC2021 | fraud |

The idea is to search the lookup table, using a partial match "smith," from the name_last field and append the results so that the results look like this

| account number | name_first | name_last | call count | values(phone_number) | value(activity_summary) | values(email) | compromisedAccount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456678 | john | smith | 3 | 1235550987 | withdraw inquiry | john.smith@company.com | jsmith001 26DEC2021 |

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/How-do-you-include-additional-fields-from-an-inputlookup-in/m-p/427417   - that suggested solution uses the OUTPUTNEW of the lookup command https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.1/SearchReference/Lookup

Answer (score 0):

Enable [WILDCARD](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/Usefieldlookupstoaddinformationtoyourevents) matching in your [lookup definition](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Lookupdefinition), then do something like:

```
<first part of search>
| lookup mylookup user AS name_last OUTPUT date intel_source
<rest of search>
```

Of course, this will only be *potentially* helpful if user names incorporate aspects of real names

If you have a John Smith whose username is rockinrutabega1970 or 829911882 or sm792ask38 ... you'll be up the proverbial creek with your attempt to "help" :)